# Show section only in specified media query

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm working on making my website responsive, but I encountered a problem.
I'm trying to hide a section to make it only phone visible, but as I try to set my `display:none` for my section and to enable it in my media query, it is overwritten by my non-media query code.

The 2 sections that I want to hide from PC users are .phone-services and .avis-phone. The problem is that, as I said if I state them as `display:none`, they will overwrite my media query.

Here is a part of my @media CSS:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 320px)
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: portrait) {

    .services {
        display:none !important;
    }

    .avis {
        display:none !important;
    }

    .phone-services {
        background:#02000A;
    }

    .avis-phone {
       background:#02000A;
       color:white;
   }
}
```

Here is a part of the other CSS that overwrites it:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shippori+Antique+B1&display=swap');

* {
    margin:0; padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none; border:none;
    font-family: "Shippori Antique B1" , sans-serif;
    transition: .2s linear;

}

html{scroll-behavior:smooth !important}

a:visited{
    visibility:hidden;
}

.phone-services {
    display:none; /*Overwrites my media query*/
}

.avis-phone {
    display:none; /*Overwrites my media query*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="phone-services">
   Section need to be shown only for mobile
</section>
<section class="avis-phone"> 
    Section need to be shown only for mobile
</section>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello @DavidThomas, sorry, I was quite in a rush, I now changed everything to make sure it's better to understand and to read.

Comment: You've already got answers, one of which you've accepted; but see this demo for a way to use CSS variables to achieve your goal: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8wpauy97/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 320px)
and (max-device-width: 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation: portrait)
```

`min-device-width` and `max-device-width` are only for actual devices. If you try to simulate that on a desktop, it won't work for you. You should use `min-width` and `max-width` instead.

Secondly, `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2` is to check device resolution, but we have various devices which we cannot simply cover with a particular resolution. I'd suggest removing it.

Another problem is from here

```
.phone-services {
    background:#02000A;
}

.avis-phone {
   background:#02000A;
   color:white;
}
```

You set `display: none`, but you don't set `display: block` (or any other visible display values)

Another point I'd like to note down that the style priority is TOP to BOTTOM when they have the same selectors. Your display style in media-query is above `display: none` like below, that will cause display problem too

```
@media {
  .phone-services {
     display: block; /*NOT WORKING*/
  }
}
.phone-services {
    display:none;
}
```

Full possible change can be

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shippori+Antique+B1&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: "Shippori Antique B1", sans-serif;
  transition: 0.2s linear;

}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}

a:visited {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.phone-services {
  display: none;
}

.avis-phone {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {

  .services {
display: none !important;
  }

  .avis {
display: none !important;
  }

  .phone-services {
background: #02000A;
display: block;
  }

  .avis-phone {
background: #02000A;
color: white;
display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="phone-services">
  Code in here
</section>
<section class="avis-phone">
  Code in here
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You always have to define `display` if you are hiding / showing them depending on @media, both in @media part and non-@media part.

Try adding it to the rules:

```
@media screen and ...

{

 .phone-services {
    background:#02000A;
    display: block; // can be block, inline-block, flex...
 }

 .avis-phone {
    background:#02000A;
    color:white;
    display: block; // can be block, inline-block, flex...
 }
}
```

Note that if you have @media part loaded before the normal one, you have to make sure to load @media part after, so it does not get overridden, or you can use `!important` with the rule (not recommended).

Comment: And the reason why you need to import @medias after is that the css cascades and only pays attention to the last change that down with element